# Access to EJB over Remote and local by interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, interface, ejb

In our JEE-application we have a basis service. This service should have an interface.

```
public interface BasisServiceA
```

The implementation of this service is a **bean**.

```
@Remote(BasisServiceA.class)
@LocalBean
public class BasisServiceAImpl implements BasisServiceA {
...
}
```

This service would be called remote, for instance over JMS, by using the **remote** interface.
Now we like to use the same service from inside our application, by using the **same interface**.
Question:

- How can we access the service from the application, by using the  interface?

Considerations:

- We don't want use the class BasisServiceAImpl directly.
- @LocalBean allows no qualifier, but @Local does
- Using the same interface as qualifiery confuses the DI?
- Is a second interface (e.g. @Local(BasisServiceALocal) ) the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to solve a non-existent problem. Just inject the remote interface in your application and leave it to the application server to figure out that you are calling the bean from the same application context and optimize (i.e. no serialization / deserialization of parameters / return values). Believe me, the guys who implement the application servers are not dumb and they've put a lot of thinking time into figuring out how to optimize their servers. This one is almost a freebie.